# Z3_solver_check returning Z3_L_UNDEF

Tags: z3, smt, formal-verification

I have a simple benchmark in Z3's C API as follows:

```
Z3_config cfg = Z3_mk_config();
Z3_context ctx = Z3_mk_context(cfg);
Z3_del_config(cfg);
Z3_solver theSolver = mk_solver(ctx);

Z3_sort domainSort = Z3_mk_bv_sort(ctx, 32);
Z3_sort rangeSort = Z3_mk_bv_sort(ctx, 8);
Z3_sort arr_sort = Z3_mk_array_sort(ctx, domainSort, rangeSort);

Z3_symbol arr_name = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "fqv");
Z3_ast fqv_arr = Z3_mk_const(ctx, arr_name, arr_sort);

Z3_ast idx = Z3_mk_concat(
        ctx, 
        Z3_mk_select(ctx, fqv_arr, Z3_mk_int(ctx, 1, domainSort)),
        Z3_mk_select(ctx, fqv_arr, Z3_mk_int(ctx, 0, domainSort))
    );
idx = Z3_mk_concat(ctx, Z3_mk_select(ctx, fqv_arr, Z3_mk_int(ctx, 2, domainSort)), idx);
idx = Z3_mk_concat(ctx, Z3_mk_select(ctx, fqv_arr, Z3_mk_int(ctx, 3, domainSort)), idx);

arr_name = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "a");
Z3_ast a_arr = Z3_mk_const(ctx, arr_name, arr_sort);

arr_name = Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, "b");
Z3_ast b_arr = Z3_mk_const(ctx, arr_name, arr_sort);

Z3_ast body = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, Z3_mk_select(ctx, a_arr, idx), Z3_mk_select(ctx, b_arr, idx));

Z3_app bound_vars[] = {(Z3_app) fqv_arr};
int num_bound_vars = 1;
int weight = 0;
Z3_ast forall = Z3_mk_forall_const(ctx, weight, num_bound_vars, bound_vars, 0, 0, body);

Z3_ast a0 = Z3_mk_select(ctx, a_arr, Z3_mk_int(ctx, 0, domainSort));
Z3_ast b0 = Z3_mk_select(ctx, b_arr, Z3_mk_int(ctx, 0, domainSort));

Z3_solver_assert(ctx, theSolver, forall);
Z3_solver_assert(ctx, theSolver, Z3_mk_eq(ctx, Z3_mk_false(ctx), Z3_mk_eq(ctx, a0, b0)));
```

Basically, there are two constraints:

- `∀fqv: a[fqv] = b[fqv]`
- `a[0] != b[0]`

The corresponding Z3_ast's are:

```
(forall ((fqv (Array (_ BitVec 32) (_ BitVec 8))))
  (! (= (select a
                (concat (select fqv #x00000003)
                        (concat (select fqv #x00000002)
                                (concat (select fqv #x00000001)
                                        (select fqv #x00000000)))))
        (select b
                (concat (select fqv #x00000003)
                        (concat (select fqv #x00000002)
                                (concat (select fqv #x00000001)
                                        (select fqv #x00000000))))))
     :weight 0))
```

and

```
(= false (= (select a #x00000000) (select b #x00000000)))
```

The result that I am getting out of `Z3_solver_check(ctx, theSolver)` is `Z3_L_UNDEF`. However, when I comment out the second constraint (`a[0] != b[0]`), it returns `Z3_L_TRUE` as expected.

Can someone please guide me on why am I getting `Z3_L_UNDEF` in this case? The result I am expecting to get out of this two constraints is `Z3_L_FALSE`. Because if arrays a and b are equal for all indices, they can't be not equal at index 0.

Here is also the output of `Z3_solver_get_reason_unknown`:

```
reason for last failure: smt tactic failed to show goal to be sat/unsat (incomplete (theory array))
```

Comment: Just as the message you're getting is telling you: Adding quantifiers makes the logic semi-decidable; i.e., the solver can return `unknown`. Note that it doesn't matter if you remove the quantified axiom or something else to make it go `sat`. So long as there's a quantifier somewhere, the solver can return `unknown`. The typical way to deal with this is via patterns which let you control quantifier instantiation; but it's not an easy task to tackle.

Comment: @alias Thank you for your answer. Are you aware of any tutorial/documentation on patterns that I can look into?

Comment: https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-e-matching-based-quantifier-instantiation is a good resource.